# PC suite for Android mobile phone⠀

Tags: android

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, and I want to transfer my Android phone data to Ubuntu like I do it in Windows. Is there any PC suite for Android phone to install on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Install [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) on your phone instead.

> With AirDroid, you can remotely access your phone or tablet‘s files,
>   notifications, messages, camera, location and many other things on a
>   computer, from anywhere.
>
> Works on Windows, Mac, Chromebook and Linux.

It will give you more or less the same functionality as a PC suite.